# How to convert %textarea with f.text_area style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to convert

```
%textarea.md-input{"data-iconlibrary" => "fa", "data-provide" => "markdown", :name => "content", :rows => "10", :style => "resize: none; display: block;"}
```

in this format

```
= f.text_area :content, ...
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
= text_area_tag "content", data: { iconlibrary: "fa", provide: "markdown" }, rows: "10", style: "resize: none; display: block;", class: "md-input"
```